# Make a Visual Studio offline installer with Linux development toolset

Tags: windows, installation, visual-studio

From this article [Install Visual Studio 2017 on low bandwidth](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-vs-inconsistent-quality-network), one can create Visual Studio offline installer for C++ or .NET development. But Linux packages are not insalled with those commands. Are there any command line options ( with --layout and --add) to install Visual Studio packages for Linux development only?

From the article, the commands download these following packages:

[image: Windows_workloads]

I want to make a offline installer for the Linux Development package as the following image:

[image: Other_toolsets]

Comment: Have you identified the name of the packages you want to install?  So I don't have to do the research to determine, how it you install the Linux development package, how is an online install performed?

Comment: If I know that I don't ask this. And I want to make offline package as my network speed fluctuate so much.

Comment: The packages have a name.  You want us to identify the package names for you?  It’s going to be at least *Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.BuildTools*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** The following procedure just works for my case. I'm not sure if this procedure is valid for all cases.

First download Visual Studio net installer from https://www.visualstudio.com/ . Open CMD where you've saved that installer. Now run the command as follows:

```
vs_community.exe --layout C:\vs2017layout --lang en-US
```

Where `C:\vs2017layout` is the path of the folder where you want to save the Visual Studio offline installer. Replace `vs_community.exe` with your downloaded edition name. Now the tricky part comes. At first when you run the command you will see a white small Visual Studio window. After that a command window prompts up and shows the download percentage. Close that window immediately after 4-5 seconds.

Now open that `C:\vs2017layout` folder, copy **Response.template.json** file in another place, delete all the files in that previous folder. Open that copied .json file in any text editor and find (Ctrl + H) `Linux` text in it. The required packages are:

```
Component.Linux.CMake
Component.MDD.Linux
Component.MDD.Linux.GCC.arm
```

Hence the full command will be:

```
vs_community.exe --layout C:\vs2017layout --add Component.Linux.CMake --add Component.MDD.Linux --add Component.MDD.Linux.GCC.arm --includeRecommended --lang en-US
```

Wait till the download complete and you get the Linux development toolset only for your offline installer. Also C++ toolset is needed. Other commands are:

* For C++:

```
vs_community.exe --layout C:\vs2017layout --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop --includeRecommended --lang en-US
```

* For C#:

```
vs_community.exe --layout C:\vs2017layout --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb --add Component.GitHub.VisualStudio --includeOptional --lang en-US
```

* For UWP:

```
vs_community.exe --layout C:\vs2017layout --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.UWP.Support Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.NetCoreAndStandard Microsoft.Net.Core.Component.SDK --lang en-US
```

#### Further Reading:

- [Install Visual Studio 2017 on low bandwidth](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-vs-inconsistent-quality-network)
- [Update a network-based installation of Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/update-a-network-installation-of-visual-studio)
- [Use command-line parameters to install](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio)

Comment: Thanks, @Ramhound for your "research-to-determine-packages" idea.

Answer (score 2):

There is no Linux version.

Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 is for Windows and Mac operating systems only.  Here is a link to the [system requirements](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/vs2017-system-requirements-vs).  I have never seen the MacOS version and I assume it has limited .NET functionality, like MonoDevelop mentioned below.

You *can* do .NET development on Linux and MacOS with [MonoDevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com/).  Not all .NET features are available in MonoDevelop, check the website for more information.

For Linux, Microsoft has [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), which is a *very* capable editor, but it is not a full development suite like Visual Studio 2017.  It has no built in compilers, debuggers, etc.  However, with its many plugins, it can do a lot.

Comment: .NET Core is used on MacOS and Linux.

Comment: Did you even bother reading the question fully?